# Необработанное исключение System.ArgumentNullException в Convert.ToBase64String

Tags: c#, decrypt

Всем привет, делаю программу для шифрования/дешифрования текста
Когда тестировал, пробовал меленький текст в пару строк и оно работало как надо, но потом же попробовал объемный текст и после нажатия на кнопку шифрования выкидывает ошибку "Crypto error" (которая собственно и обрабатывается в коде через catch ) и необработанное исключение **ArgumentNullException**

> ArgumentNullException не обработано 
>   Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentNullException" в mscorlib.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Значение не может быть неопределенным.

При этом подсвечивает строку в коде:

`textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedData);`

Вот выкладываю полный код моей кнопки Шифрования

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        try
        {
            if (publickey.Length == 0)
            {
                _ispub_xml = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Неверный открытый ключ");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                rsa.FromXmlString(publickey);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Проблема с RSA \n" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ss)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ss.ToString());
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            EncryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(data, false);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Crypto error... \n" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedData);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            data.SetValue((byte)0, i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < EncryptedData.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            EncryptedData.SetValue((byte)0, i);
        }
    }
```

Сразу скажу что, не все я писал с нуля поэтому видимо и возникают подводные камни, но просто хочу заставить работать :)

Comment: Понял почему ошибка возникает `"Алгоритмы шифрования с открытым ключом используют буфер фиксированного размера"`, Вот нашел такой выход : `"Стоит заметить, что длина текстового сообщения не может превышать длину ключа, поэтому в данном проекте была реализована разбивка текста на блоки, каждый из которых шифруется, а затем они, обратно склеиваются, что позволяет набирать текст неограниченного размера."` Как такое сделать?

Comment: EncryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(data, false); это отрабатывает нормально?

Comment: Вообще да, на нее нигде не ругалось

Comment: Брекпойнт поставьте, проверьте.

Comment: @Андрей Ошибок не вижу, если я все правильно сделал [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/6OMf0l1.png)

Comment: В этом месте надо нажать F10 и посмотреть выполнится ли строчка без ошибок

Comment: говорят, что rsa не предназначен для шифрования больших объектов. И рекомендуют использовать или класс Rijndael  или статью [тут](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html) [источник](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659898/bad-data-cryptographicexception)

Comment: @user2455111 да, я уже это узнал, на эту статью уже сам наткнулся, и оно действительно работает хотя не сильно понимаю как именно оно работает, видимо уже шифрует не на чистом **rsa** а через **RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter**

Comment: @Андрей вот [скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/eTbPusL.png) видимо и там оно вылетает уже. Наверное буду мудрить с битностью ключа

Comment: @PavelFedorov, всё верно, EncryptedData не инициализируется, поэтому ArgumentNullException, вам нужно для начала textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedData); перенести внутрь try блока, ну и разобраться уже почему там эксепшн бросается